# Density of a random sample from the family of absolute continuous distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of all absolute continuous distributions on $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a simple random sample from $\mathcal{P}$. My task is to show that 
$$T(X) = (X_{1:n}, \ldots X_{n:n})$$
is complete and sufficient statistic (thus minimal sufficient statistic).
I wanted to solve this problem using [factorization theorem](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/). However I don't know how to find the density function:
$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n).$$
I would appreciate any tips or hints.